Finding the imaginary part of $\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right)\right)$, where $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$
I am looking for the imaginary part of the following expression
$$\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right)\right)$$
where $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$.
The attempt I made was the following
$$\begin{align}
\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right) &= \ln(e^{ix}\cos(x)) \tag1\\
&= \ln(\cos(x))+ix \tag2 \\[6pt]
\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right)\right) &= \ln(\ln(\cos(x))+ix) \tag3 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln^2(\cos(x))+x^2\right)+i\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\ln(\cos(x))}\right) \tag4
\end{align}$$
So
$$Im\left(\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right)\right)\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{x}{\ln(\cos(x))}\right) \tag5$$
Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing an additional argument of $\pi$?

If you are taking every step to be the principal branch, then this is not correct. Think about in which quadrant $\log(\cos x) + ix$ lives.

Oh now I see!!  I didn’t realize what the ln(cos(x)) term was doing from the given domain.
